# Como percorrer atributos de um JSON?

Tags: javascript, json, loop, foreach

estou tentando percorrer atributos de um json, estou tentando dessa forma

```
for (var i = 0, length = r.length; i < length; i++) {
   for (var i2 = 0,length = r[i].lenght; i2 < length; i2++ ){
       console.log("teste"+r[i][i2]);
   }
}
```

como eu faço isso corretamente?

o Json está vindo irregular, pois quando o service recebe um valor nulo do banco ele não seta o campo no json

```
[
{
    "nome": "Victor Siqueira",
    "login": "victor.justino@spcm.com.br",
    "senha": "ef797c8118f02dfb649607dd5d3f8c7623048c9c063d532cc95c5ed7a898a64f",
    "tempoSessao": 15,
    "acesso": [
        {
            "idTela": "AA00"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "nome": "",
    "tempoSessao": 0,
    "acesso": []
},
{
    "nome": "",
    "login": "as",
    "senha": "1234",
    "tempoSessao": 0,
    "acesso": []
},
{
    "nome": "",
    "login": "as2",
    "senha": "9876",
    "tempoSessao": 0,
    "acesso": []
},
{
    "nome": "",
    "login": "as3",
    "senha": "9876",
    "tempoSessao": 0,
    "acesso": []
},
{
    "nome": "",
    "login": "as4",
    "senha": "a123",
    "tempoSessao": 0,
    "acesso": []
},
{
    "nome": "",
    "login": "as5",
    "senha": "54d5cb2d332dbdb4850293caae4559ce88b65163f1ea5d4e4b3ac49d772ded14",
    "tempoSessao": 0,
    "acesso": []
},
{
    "nome": "",
    "login": "PFernandes",
    "senha": "54d5cb2d332dbdb4850293caae4559ce88b65163f1ea5d4e4b3ac49d772ded14",
    "tempoSessao": 0,
    "acesso": []
},
{
    "nome": "",
    "tempoSessao": 0,
    "acesso": []
},
{
    "nome": "",
    "tempoSessao": 0,
    "acesso": []
},
{
    "nome": "",
    "tempoSessao": 0,
    "acesso": []
},
{
    "nome": "",
    "tempoSessao": 0,
    "acesso": []
},
{
    "nome": "",
    "tempoSessao": 0,
    "acesso": []
},
{
    "nome": "",
    "tempoSessao": 0,
    "acesso": []
},
{
    "nome": "",
    "tempoSessao": 0,
    "acesso": []
},
{
    "nome": "",
    "tempoSessao": 0,
    "acesso": []
},
{
    "nome": "",
    "tempoSessao": 0,
    "acesso": []
}
```

]

Comment: Como está seu arquivo json? Poste ai pra gente ver.

Comment: ta postado diego

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Acho que a melhor forma é você trabalhar com objetos.

Se você atribuir tua string JSON a um objeto você poderá acessá-la de forma mais fácil.

```
var arrayJson = JSON.parse("tua string JSON");
arrayJson.forEach(function(pessoa){
  var acesso = pessoa.acesso;
  acesso.forEach(function(acesso)){
    if (acesso != null)
      //acesso.idTela - para acessar a propriedade pelo nome
  }
})
```

Não sei se fui claro, mas qualquer dúvida te respondo.

Comment: ahh entendi, vlw man

Comment: Você também pode usar o for da mesma maneira, não tenho certeza mas acho que o for é mais performático.